# How do I center align multiple columns in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center-align Card 1 so that it lines up nicely in the center of the page with the rest of the cards (Card 2, Card 3, Card 4, Card 5).

I can't seem to find the solution for this after trying multiple ways.

How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  
  initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="containter">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
        <div class="card card-body h-100">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card card-body h-100">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card 2</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
              </p>
              <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="">Get More</a></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card card-body h-100">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card 3</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
              </p>
              <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="">Get More</a></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card card-body h-100">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card 4</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
              </p>
              <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="">Get More</a></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card card-body h-100">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card 5</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                <br>
              </p>
              <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="">Get More</a></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Image Reference for the description]

Comment: You want it on top of the other cards? also you have `<div class="containter">` instead of container

Comment: You want **Card 1** in center of the page with 4-col size, and want others to be beneath it in new rows side by side with 2 cards per row?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you wanted exactly but I've managed to get something to what your description is asking for.

Changes I made:

`d-flex flex column`

`col-md-8` and `col-sm-6`

```html
<!doctype html> 

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags  -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  
  initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  


 
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">

        <!-- card -->
        <div class="col-md-8 py-2"> 
            <div class="card card-body"> 
                <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5> 
                <p class="card-text"> 
                  <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                </p>  

            </div> 
        </div> 
        
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!-- Row starts -->
            <div class="row justify-content-center"> 
                <!-- Labor Market Data card -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 py-2"> 
                    <div class="card card-body h-100"> 
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card 2</h5> 
                        <p class="card-text"> 
                            <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
                        </p>  
                        <!-- Get More button -->
                        <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="">Get More</a></button>
                    </div> 
                </div> 


                <!-- Publications card -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 py-2"> 
                    <div class="card card-body h-100"> 
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card 3</h5> 
                              <p class="card-text"> 
                                  <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                              </p> 
                                        
                              <!-- Get More button -->
                              <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href= "">Get More</a></button>            
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>
            <!-- Row ends -->

            <!-- row starts -->
            <div class="row justify-content-center"> 
                <!--card -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 py-2"> 
                      <div class="card card-body h-100"> 
                          <h5 class="card-title">Card 4</h5> 
                          <p class="card-text"> 
                                <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                          </p> 
                          <!-- Get More button -->
                          <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href= "">Get More</a></button>
                                  </div> 
                </div>
                <!-- card -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 py-2"> 
                    <div class="card card-body h-100"> 
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card 5</h5> 
                        <p class="card-text"> 
                            <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                          <br>
                        </p> 
                        <!-- Get More button -->
                        <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style= "text-decoration:none" href="">Get More</a></button>
                                  </div> 
                </div>     
            </div>
            <!-- row ends -->
        </div>
        

    </div>
</div>




<!-- Container ends here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you want the **Card 1** to at the center and top of the page. The following code snippet will do that.

Things that I noticed and changed in your code are:

1. You spelled `container` class as `containter`.
2. As you wanted **Card 1** to be in the center at the top row. I added it to its own row and gave `justify-content-center` class to it.
3. Kept all the other cards in other row.

So, you can find the updated code below with comments about the change as well:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags  -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  
  initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">  <!-- added class to center card -->

        <!-- card -->
        <div class="col-sm-8 py-2"> <!-- changed card width to 8 from 4 -->
          <div class="card card-body h-100">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
              <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
            </p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- ended row for Card 1 here -->
      
      <div class="row">  <!-- started new row for rest of the cards -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <!-- Row starts -->
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <!-- Labor Market Data card -->
            <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
              <div class="card card-body h-100">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card 2</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
                </p>
                <!-- Get More button -->
                <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="">Get More</a></button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Publications card -->
            <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
              <div class="card card-body h-100">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card 3</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                </p>

                <!-- Get More button -->
                <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="">Get More</a></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Row ends -->

          <!-- row starts -->
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <!--card -->
            <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
              <div class="card card-body h-100">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card 4</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                </p>
                <!-- Get More button -->
                <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="">Get More</a></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- card -->
            <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
              <div class="card card-body h-100">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card 5</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  <br>
                </p>
                <!-- Get More button -->
                <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="">Get More</a></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- row ends -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thank you!!